# what is the shortcut to close all the opener-closer arrow in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

> I am using sublime text 2, sometime i face a problem to close manually
>   all the opener-closer arrow

so i want to ask that is there any shortcut for that in sublime text 2, i want to close all the arrow with a shortcut like below image:

[image]

can any one tell me the shortcut for that, please

Comment: @ Basim Hennawi thansk its working

Comment: @BasimHennawi you can flag